# Angular Bootstrap giving error after installing in npm

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have installed jquery, popper.js and bootstrap in npm cli. After installing I added the style reference in angularcli.json for bootstrap. When I run the project the following error is showing. Please help.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
    at C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at browserslist (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:274:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:189:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:201:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:228:20)
    at LazyResult.async (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:225:27)
    at LazyResult.then (C:\Users\hasan\angulartest\boottest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:131:21)
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 4:14-127
 @ multi ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the bootstrap version 4 has bugs. I changed the bootstraps version from 4.0.0 to 3.0.0 in packages.json and run command npm install. After that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This look like somehow related problem.
Please look at this:

> - From **"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2" to "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2"**, take out **"^"**
> - Then **npm install**
> - Then **ng serve**

**Source:** [angular-cli/issues/9020](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020)